# Is my question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/where-does-king-th%C3%A9oden-shop-for-clothes

> **Lord of the Rings joke/pun/wordplay:**
>
> Where does [Théoden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9oden), King of Rohan, shop for clothes?
>
> Hints and clarification:
>
> 1. > King Théoden lives in *Rohan*
> 2. > You've probably heard of this well-known clothing store. It's an American multinational clothing and accessories retailer.
> 3. > The *name* of the store that you've probably heard of is where the **wordplay** comes in, since that store's name is mentioned in the Lord of the Rings books with respect to the King *and where he lives*.

So that's the question. It was initially put on hold as off-topic, **but I have edited it since then.** This question is a joke/riddle/wordplay puzzle thingy so I think it should be on-topic. **Is this on topic? if not, then why?**

---

A main concern of mine is that people might think it's off-topic just because they don't know the answer. In case that affects the situation in any way, I will explain the answer below. Obviously, don't look at the answer if you're still trying to solve it. :)

**Answer explanation below [SPOILERS]:**

> A: "The Gap of Rohan" - The Gap is an American multinational clothing and accessories retailer. The [Gap of Rohan](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gap_of_Rohan) is a location in the Lord of the Rings near/around Rohan, where the King lives.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2809/39)

Answer (score 1):

It's not on topic simply because it's not a puzzle. Puns with the punchline removed are not puzzles; they require no actual thought, just Googling lists of vaguely relevant things.